# GPS Accuracy Calculation

Tags: android

I developed GPS app in Android, it returns the gps value with 20 meters accuracy,
But my actual position is 20 meters away from the returned location value.

From this how to calculate my original position value by using returned location value and accuracy value.

Please help me

Thanks
Nandha

Comment: We have no control over what GPS returns. For a more accurate value to be returned by the GPS sensor, you should not be inside a building while using GPS. Go out and try, the position returned will be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The whole point of the accuracy level means that you're guaranteed to be within X distance. Your returned location value was 20 meters from your actual position; the accuracy was 20 meters. That's the best you can do with that accuracy. You should get better accuracy than that if you're using GPS versus simple cell tower triangulation.

EDIT: Although I suppose in theory you could take multiple measurements, each measurement making a circle of [accuracy] radius, and narrow it down by where those sections intersect. But from a single returned value and accuracy, no.

Comment: Actually what I have seen on my garmin gps multiple samples won't help because in a single place over a short time the error is consistently the same. However the next day the error can be totally different. I suppose this happens because the satellites move so you do not see the same satellites can even be more or less.

Comment: @Eelke That makes sense. If it was as easy as I made it sound, I'm sure that'd be standard in most GPS software by now. ;)